# Do I always need a template for each route in Ember 2?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

Say suppose I have a people's template (people.hbs), and I want to list all the people that is retrieved from a GET to http://backendserver/api/people.
However in future I decided to implement something that requires me to sort these people based on the data that I get from http://backendserver/api/vehicle_people. In this data there is only the people id and the vehicle id so I can't just connect people and its associated vehicle information together , I also get vehicle data from http://backendserver/api/vehicles.

Some of the confusion on how to implement this in Ember2 is

1. Should I put all this info inside routers/people.js
   something like this

   ```
   export default Ember.Route.extend({
     model(){
          return Ember.RSVP.hash({
              people_with_vehicle: //find from this.store all the people and the vehicle ,
              people_with_no_vehicle:,
              all people: 
          })
     }
   ```
2. How should I load the data for http://backendserver/api/vehicle_people if I don't want to create any specific route or template ?. In ember2 it does like an automatic load based on the route you go to e.g if you defined in your /adapters/application.js

   ```
   export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
      namespace: 'api',
        host:'http://backendserver/'
    });
   ```

Comment: I don't understand the title of your question, or how it's related to the content. Of course a route needs a template--otherwise, what would be rendered? Of course, the template could in theory be auto-generated.

Answer (score 1):

Your "vehicle_people" endpoint is best mapped to an Ember Data model called `VehiclePeople`, which would be:

```
DS.Model.extend({
  person: DS.belongsTo('person'),
  vehicle: DS.belongsTo('vehicle')
})
```

There are other approaches, but let us map, at the model level, which vehicles people drive. First we establish the relationship between people and your little two-attribute people-to-vehicle map called `vehicle_people`:

```
vehiclePeople: DS.hasMany('vehicle_people', { async: true })
```

This will send a network request, or network requests, to the `vehicle_people` endpoints, based on the person's ID, whenever this field is accessed. We'll see an alternative way to handle that in a minute.

Now a computed property serves to gives us a list of the actual vehicles.

```
vehicles: Ember.computed.mapBy('vehiclePeople', 'vehicle')
```

and

```
hasVehicle: Ember.computed.bool('vehicles.length', 0)
```

Creating lists of people with or without vehicles is not a matter of the model; it's pre-calculation that you almost certainly want to do in your controller:

```
Ember.Controller.extend({
  peopleWithVehicles: Ember.computed.filterBy('model', 'hasVehicle')
```

and so on.

If you want to preload the `vehicle_people` relationships, so Ember Data does not attempt to go out and get them one at a time, the best way is to do that in the `beforeModel` hook:

```
...route
beforeModel() { return this.store.find('vehicle_people'); }
```

#### Is this the right way to normalize the model?

Having the little model-but-not-a-model which does nothing more than contains mapping from one model (people) to another (vehicles) is probably not the right way to organize your models and endpoints. You would be much, much better off simply include `vehicles` directly in `person`. What's the roadblock to doing that?

Comment: Since Ember is thinking of removing Controller in their future releases would you still recommend this step Ember.Controller.extend({
  peopleWithVehicles: Ember.computed.filterBy('model', 'hasVehicle') ?

Answer (score 0):

Your route is nothing to do with your model, in terms of naming convention, although you would probably often have them the same, and nest your routes to create your UI.

Ember does not do any magical matching of your route name to the api endpoint name. Ember Data does a little name magic to match the API endpoint to the model in the store.

1.

I assume these would all be people, and that they would have an attribute which defines whther they are vehicle people or non vehicle people. You can also include associated models in a single API endpoint, if it makes sense.

2. Include the model on the route that matches the template you wish to use that data on, regardless of what the route is called.

Comment: So you mean it is ok to load multiple models for a route like in routers/people.js `model(){ return Ember.RSVP.hash( people_with_vehicles: <logic to filter out from the this.store>, people_without_vehicles:<logic to filter out from this.store> )}`